# R find same values in column for unique values of another column

Tags: r, unique

here´s some sample data

```
sample = data.frame("col1" = c("val1", "val1", "val1", "val1", "val2", "val2", "val2", "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3"),
                    "col2" = c("this", "that", "some", "thing", "thing", "that", "some", "diff", "some", "this", "that"))
```

I would like to determine each entry of column col2 which appears of every unique value of column col1. Is this somehow possible?
This would be the result of the sample data:

```
result = c("that", "some")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a single `col2` value appear multiple times for one `col1` value? Like `"this"` two times within `"val1"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `intersect`. Here's a quick and dirty way:

**CODE**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(sample) 

# Split data.table into different chunks based on unique values in col1
# output is a list where each entry is a data.table 
l <- split(dt, by = "col1")

# Find the intersection of all values in col2 
Reduce(intersect, lapply(1:length(l), function(z) as.character(l[[z]]$col2)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> Reduce(intersect, lapply(1:length(l), function(z) as.character(l[[z]]$col2)))
[1] "that" "some"
```

Answer (score 1):

A (quick and dirty) solution in `base R`:

```
sample_list <- split(sample, sample$col1)
for (i in 1:length(sample_list)) sample_list[[i]] <- sample_list[[i]]$col2
Reduce(intersect, sample_list)
[1] "that" "some"
```

**EDIT:**

A `data.table` solution inspired by Matt's `dplyr` answer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample)
n <- uniqueN(sample$col1)
sample[, .N, by = .(col1, col2)][, .N, by = col2][N == n, col2]
[1] that some
```

This solution will be fast on a big dataset.

**EDIT 2:**

Playing around with `dcast` which is available in `data.table`:

```
present_in <- colSums(!is.na(dcast(sample, col1 ~ col2, value.var = "col2")))
names(present_in)[present_in == 3][-1]
[1] "some" "that"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a bit of a round about way using `dplyr`.

```
require(dplyr)

sets <- length(unique(sample$col1))

s <- sample %>%
    group_by(col2) %>%
    summarise(n = n_distinct()) %>%
    filter(n == sets)

result <- s$col2
[1] some that
```

Comment: this is not necessarily correct. Could have multiple entries of `col2` for the same value of `col1`. could be fixed by adding `distinct` in second line of `s <- ...`

Comment: `dplyr` has `n_distinct()` to replace `length(unique())`

Comment: agree with @bouncyball solution correctly not correct.

Comment: good call. will fix

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to do it using dplyr:

```
split(sample,sample$col1)%>%
Reduce(function(dtf1,dtf2) inner_join(dtf1,dtf2,by="col2"), .)%>%select(col2)%>%print()

  col2
1 that
2 some
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty base `R` solution:

```
names(which(table(unlist(aggregate(sample$col2, list(sample$col1), unique)[, 2])) == length(unique(sample$col1))))

[1] "some" "that"
```